# Can I convert my code using await to use call-backs instead

Tags: c#, async-await

I am new at C#, and converting some Swift Bluetooth LE code to C# UWP.

I have code working that uses async/await.  But to make it similar to what I have in Swift, I think I'd would ideally like get a callback when the APIs that are Async complete.

For example, swift code:

```
private func connect_to( per : CBPeripheral) {
    centralManager?.connect( per, options: nil)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([transferServiceUUID])
}
```

The second func is a call-back.  Currently in C# I have things like this:

```
private async void ConnectByID_OrAddr( UInt64 btAddr)
{
  btLEDev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAddr);
  if (btLEDev == null) {
     // TODO: failure notifications...
     return;
  }

  GattDeviceServicesResult result = 
      await btLEDev.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
  // etc.
}
```

I saw references to using Delegates in C#, but it wasn't clear to me how to do this with the API calls.

Comment: Give async await a chance, it really makes code more readable, and from a what it does perspective it is similar with the callback version of the code.

Comment: This question is unclear. You can make a custom delegate definition, use Action/Functions or make a callback interface and inherit with a class. But async is way more readable.

Comment: My problem is that I could not figure out how to do a custom delegate definition.  But, at this point I think I'm convinced to make it work with async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ContinueWith` to chain `Tasks` in C# the same way `Promisses` are chained with `then` in Javascript.

```
private static void ConnectByID_OrAddr2(UInt64 btAddr)
{
    BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAddr)
        .ContinueWith(btLEDevTask => // Callback for when first task completes
        {
            var btLEDev = btLEDevTask.Result;
            if (btLEDev == null)
            {
                // TODO: failure notifications...
                return Task.FromResult<GattDeviceServicesResult>(null);
            }
            return btLEDev.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(resultTask =>// Callback for when second task completes
        {
            var result = resultTask.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Result:" + result);
        });
}
```

***Oppinion***:

Please do not use the `ContinueWith` version unless there is a good reason for it. Personally I find this style of code very hard to follow and would prefer the async/await version any time. You should try to embrace the features of any programming language you use instead of trying to make the code look like the language you previously worked in.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for, but I think your comment to use the language facilities is a good one.  The Swift style is to have a large dependence on delegate callbacks, and it can get a bit overwhelming -- and messy.